# How to display a resource dictionary items in design view?

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary, designview

I want to display my resource dictionary items with my custom design view, i want to make a `ListView` to show the keys with the values. and can edit withing the design view.
-i want to be able to edit my dictionary within visual studio desiner.

[image: i want to be able to edit my dictionary within visual studio desiner]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Keys and Values properties of resourceDictionary instance below.

```
 string exeFilePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase;
 string exeDirPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(exeFilePath);
 string targetFile = "subFolder\\ResourceDictionary.xaml";
 string dictionaryPath = new Uri(System.IO.Path.Combine(exeDirPath, targetFile)).LocalPath;
 string xamlString = File.ReadAllText(dictionaryPath);
 ResourceDictionary resourceDictionary = (ResourceDictionary)XamlReader.Parse(xamlString);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i mean in design mode, i want to show the keys and values in a listview, like usercontrol you can edit it, in visual studio designer and you can edit it in code. so i want to make a visual view for my resource dictionary at design time.